# CSS transition speed change based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div element whose width is determined by the users mouse position inside a defined area. Upon entering this area the transition should be smooth, until the width has catched up to the current mouse position and smooth again when leaving the area and the width goes back to normal. In the time between the transition should be fast, so the width is responsive to the mouse position.

Html

```
<div class="widthChanging"></div>
<div class="HoverA"></div>
```

CSS

```
.widthChanging {
    transition: width 300ms cubic-bezier(.45,.1,.14,.61);
  }

.HoverA:hover + .widthChanging {
 width: calc(0.001 / var(--mouse-x, 0) * 100vw);
 transition: width 0s;
}
```

I get the mouse position using Javascript.
When leaving the "HoverA" area the width returns smoothly, because the transition speed defined in "widthChanging" takes over. Sadly I cant (I think) do the same for entering the "HoverA" area. My only idea would be waiting the transition time before assigning a class with the slower transition time, but this seems like a bad solution to me and would also require more Javascript.

I hope you have some more elegant ideas than me :)

Comment: can you also share the JS code so we have a Complete code to run and see

Comment: Javascript is based on https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/eBZgPB

Comment: yes but it's better to re-create a working code so we can see the behavior .. we also need some CSS, etc

Comment: I have created a working codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYBvXJ

Comment: Ok and what is the issue ... why you don't remove the transition on the hover and you will have smooth effect on enter/exit

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly is the expected result. Can you explain better this point?

Comment: If I remove the transition on the hover element I do have a smooth transition, but if you start moving your mouse faster, you will see that the width doesent keep up with the mouse movement which just feels bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by waiting and then assigning a class with the new transition speed using javascript. I dont think that this is the best way to do it.
Here the codepen https://codepen.io/Teiem/pen/EReJPx

html

```
<div class="HoverA" onmouseover="SpeedEnter2()" onclick="SpeedEnter2()"onmouseout="SpeedLeave2()"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function SpeedEnter2() {
goVar = setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById("SpeedId2").classList.add('Fast');
}, 300);
```

Css

```
.Fast {
 transition: width 0s !important;
}
```